# Ugly characters displayed when saving byte array to a file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, dataoutputstream

I have a Text file in the server. I am downloading that file from the client. I have given the file path where to it should be saved `fi`.

The text file created, and it has some ugly characters in it, and not Strings. How can i correct it ?

The format of the output is;

```
sNULdNULiNULdNUL
```

A character in the text file is printed, followed by **NUL** in bold. what is this and how can i get rid of it?

```
FileOutputStream f= new FileOutputStream(fi);

DataOutputStream d= new DataOutputStream(f);

String fc;
while((fc  = re.readLine()) !=null)  
{  
System.out.println(fc);
d.writeChars(fc);
d.flush();

}
```

UPDATE

```
€À€À€À€À€À€À€À€À€À€À€À€À€À€À€
```

Update 2

```
InputStreamReader st= new InputStreamReader(
                    s.getInputStream());
            re= new BufferedReader(st);
```

and `s` is the `socket` here. `re` has been initialize as `BufferedReader re;`

```
try {
            s= new Socket("localhost", "2222");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`writeChars` writes each char to the underlying output stream as a 2-byte value, high byte first.So if you have multibyte character in your stream it will result ugly displayed characters in your output.Use proper encoding for your streams

<s>Try replacing `d.writeChars(fc);` with `d.writeUTF(fc);` .Hope thats helps</s>

If I am getting you correct use `US-ASCII` encoding for inputput stream.

```
InputStreamReader st= new InputStreamReader(
                s.getInputStream(),"US-ASCII");
        re= new BufferedReader(st);
```

Comment: how can i use proper encoding ? Sorry but i am new to this

Comment: First I'd read about character vs. byte oriented streams: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/stream.html

Comment: I have updated the post with the output, i still didn't get the proper output

Comment: what charset your file have on server.can you post a string from original file

Comment: `abcabcabcabcabca101
` <--- this is the content of the original text file.

Comment: Then it shouldn't be a problem with `writeChars` cause it's a simple text file. I suspect your `re` object. Can you post relevant code

Comment: BTW whats default encoding for your JVM

Comment: I am using java version "1.6.0_26". it has to be the default JVM. it has to be UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Strings, when you wish to store them in memory, write them to file or send them across the internet, need to be encoded to bytes. There are many encoding systems to do this in.

`writeChars` writes each character as two bytes, which is what you have already seen.

`writeUTF` does something not-human readable:

> Writes a string to the underlying output stream using Java modified
>   UTF-8 encoding in a machine-independent manner.
>
> First, two bytes are written to the output stream as if by the
>   writeShort method giving the number of bytes to follow. This value is
>   the number of bytes actually written out, not the length of the
>   string. Following the length, each character of the string is output,
>   in sequence, using the modified UTF-8 encoding for the character. If
>   no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented by the
>   total number of bytes written to the output stream. This will be at
>   least two plus the length of str, and at most two plus thrice the
>   length of str.

If you wish to write characters to file, without much fuss, use a [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html). It'll in most cases assume the proper defaults for writing a human readable file.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

while((fc  = re.readLine()) !=null) {  
    bw.write(fc);
    bw.newLine();
    bw.flush();
}
bw.close();
```

Comment: Is there a mistake here. `fw.writeLine(fw)` ? i think you  meant `fc` anyway, writeLine is not recognised ? help

Comment: Tried it. It gives me one long line of junk values and then prints the actual text in the file. Any clue . output similar to `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXabcdefghijk` where `xxxxxxx` are the junk values

Comment: The junk is probably non-character data that you received from the server.

Comment: Is there a way i could get rid of it?

Comment: `Socket`, like the `DataOutputStream` is a rather low-level api class. For downloading data from a URL, you better use the `Url` class or the apache commons `HttpClient`.

Comment: Can't we do a validation, to check if its a valid character and then print?

Comment: What's running on that port? A http server? Something wilder? If it is a common protocol, it's probably best to let a library class like URL or HttpClient figure it out for you. If it's something custom, you can parse it yourself. Maybe you can use  [Character.isLetterOrDigit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit%28char%29) as a coarse sieve to sift out the initial garbage. You're probably best off reading the characters one by one then using an ordinary `Reader`, until you're done with the garbage, then wrap it with the `BufferedReader`